# I don't know about pre and post incrementation

Tags: c, increment, operator-keyword, post-increment

Why is result 12 instead of 13
So what i think is that first k/j is evaluated which gives 0
then j-0 becomes 7
then 5 + 7 = 12
then 12++ at the end of evaluating anything
so answer should be 13 but its 12
I would REALLY appreciate if someone can explain it.

```
int i = 5,j = 7,k = 3;
    int result = i+++j-k/j;
    printf("%d",result);
```

Comment: The answer is 5 plus 7, since you're post-incrementing `i`.

Comment: `12++` doesn't make sense since `12` isn't a variable.

Comment: *"I don know about pre and post incrementation"* - So learn something about them! - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkxFPJG5paw

Answer (score 2):

You've been bitten by operator precedence and integer division. Everything in this expression below, spaced out to be readable, is done using integer math.

```
int result = i++ + j - k / j;
```

Or

```
int result = 5 + 7 - 3 / 7;
```

Since `i++` increments `i` *after* it's been evaluated, `i` is 5 for the calculation and 6 afterwards.

Division has a higher precedence than addition or subtraction, so it's really this:

```
int result = 5 + 7 - (3 / 7);
```

All integer math has the decimal part truncated, so `3/7` is 0.

```
int result = 5 + 7 - 0;
```

There's your 12.

And this is why it's best to avoid relying on the pre or post nature of incrementing operators in larger expressions, they make the expression difficult to understand and are prone to mistakes. Either use them stand alone as a shorthand for `i += 1`, as in `for( int i = 0; i < something; i++ )`, or write `i += 1`.

Comment: so ++ is never applied?

Comment: @noobPoopDeck It is applied, but it's to `i` and ***after*** `i` is used. Print `i` and you'll see it's 6.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
int result = (i + j) - (k / j); i = i + 1;
```

Matches the actual operations done.

Answer (score 0):

```
i+++j-k/j   ==  i++ + j - k/j
```

**evaluation order** :

```
1) k/j = 0
3) i++ + j
   5++ + 7 = 12
3) (i+++j)-k/j
    12-0 = 12
```

now **i** will be incremented to 6

So answer is 12 not 13.

To get 13 try this

```
++i+j-k/j;
```

Comment: Operations of equal precedence are usually done left-to-right (there are a couple exceptions to this rule).

Comment: your "evaluation order" is a possible order but not guaranteed, e.g. `i + j` might be evaluated before `k / j`

Comment: @JohnHascall I think you are mixing up associativity with order-of-evaluation.  `f() - g() - h()` is left-associative but the functions might be called in any order

Comment: @M.M I think / has higher priority than + so k/j should evaluate first. and after that it should be from left to right. I changed my solution .

Comment: @Avi you are mixing up priority with order of evaluation

Comment: @M.M yes, in your example the functions can be called in any order, but the actual mathematical operations (with the results of the functions) are carried out in the "expected" mathematical order (or in a way which is equivalent).  (12 - 7 - 3) will always be 2 never 8.  But, the additions in (12 + 7 + 3) can be done in either order.